# How to wrap a certain number of divs in another div?

Tags: jquery, wrapall

What's the best way to wrap a certain number of divs into another div? For example if I have 19 divs, how do I use `wrapAll` to group 9 of them and still group them even if it's under 9.

This is what I have now. It works if it's 4 but when I tried to do more, it would duplicate content from other elements.

```
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function (i) {
 var line_wrap = $(".line_wrap");
 for(var i=-1; i<line_wrap.length; i=i+5) {
  $('.line_wrap:eq('+i+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-1)+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-2)+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-3)+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-4)+')').wrapAll('<div class="wrap">');
  }
});
```

Comment: can you share a sample HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```js
var size = 10; //define how many elements you want in each wrapper
var items = $('.item'); //the collection of all your items
var container; //this will be used to add the items in it.

$.each(items, function(i, item) { 
  //this expression checks if we need to create a new container
  if (i % size === 0) {
    container = $('<div class="wrapped"></div>'); //create a new container
    $('body').append(container); //add the new container to the body
  }
  $(item).appendTo(container); //add the item to the container
});
```

```css
.wrapped {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
<div class="item">11</div>
<div class="item">12</div>
<div class="item">13</div>
<div class="item">14</div>
<div class="item">15</div>
<div class="item">16</div>
```

---- AN EDIT FOLLOWING YOUR COMMENT

Before running my code, this is what you get

[image]

You can just wrap the content of `.message-contain`

If you want to run my code for every `.message-contain`
PS: you have multiple id="content". Id's must be unique. You will run into problems if you keep the same id.

PS2: You need to adapt the code to your example. You can't simply copy-paste into your code and expect it to work. I'm appending directly to the body which is not what you need. It was just an example.

[Here's an example of what I think you're trying to achieve.](https://jsfiddle.net/nh1au2pf/)

Comment: This is great but I'm having a problem where it takes words from other elements and adds them to others. Here's what I'm talking about - https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/gOpJErJ

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added numbers to show the problem, see how the second section gets wrapped into the first. Not suppose to do that.

Comment: See how it takes all the words and wraps them? I’ve been trying for months to find a way to do it by each section and not by all.

Comment: Well it's set to wrap every 10 elements. var size = 10; //define how many elements you want in each wrapper. If you want to wrap them by content you need to wrap them with a for each loop.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Here's he fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nh1au2pf/

Comment: Thanks again for the help.